# How to show the previous frame of android media player ,when it was in pause mode while configuration changes

Tags: android

Now I am working with android media player. So I got a problem with media player while user rotating the screen from portrait to landscape and vice versa.

User pauses the video in portrait mode at some frame,So when user rotates the screen I want to show the same screen where it was paused.
In this case, I am able to save the previous position of the player and setting back but here I can see a black screen instead of the previous frame.

**Code:1**

```
//Here i am saving previous position of mediplayer
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putLong(KEY_IS_MAIN_VIDEO_CURRENT_POSITION, mMainVideoMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

**2.Getting previous value**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.videoplay_new_layout);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mIsConfigChanged = true;           


            mMainVideoPreviousPosition = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_IS_MAIN_VIDEO_CURRENT_POSITION);


        }
```

**3.Setting the saved previous value back to player when on prepared called**

```
mMainVideoMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mMainVideoMediaPlayer.start();
//Setting previous value::::

mMainVideoMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) mMainVideoPreviousPosition);

//Making player pause because mediaplayer player previous state is paused in potrait mode:::

mMainVideoMediaPlayer.pause();


}
});
```

Comment: Put your logic in Fragment and your can use setRetainInstace(true) in your Fragment, and use your Activity to attach same Fragment in your onCreate().

Comment: I have done that also,But its not working.Here the problem is with surface view,Its getting destroyed and recreating.My whole logic about mediaplyer creation and setting data source,everything is there in surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) .So i am unable to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried the comment part, then try this and let me know.

```
mMainVideoMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mMainVideoMediaPlayer.start();


mMainVideoMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) mMainVideoPreviousPosition);

//Making player pause because mediaplayer player previous state is paused in potrait mode:::

mMainVideoMediaPlayer.pause();

//Try this code below like hack for now.
//---------------
<playButton>.pefromClick(); //It will start playing 
<pauseButton>.perfromClick(); //immediately pause it.
//------------------


}
});
```